# Angular, embed live chat on my website

Tags: angular, chat, embed

Is there an API I can use to create a live chat on my website ? Like I can customize the html but all the messages are hosted on an external website.

Comment: https://rocket.chat/ but you have to host it yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use a live chat plugin for adding live chat to website.

There are many products available in the market:

Kommunicate
Zendesk Chat
Tawk to
Intercom
Drift
Crisp
and many more

Firstly, choose a live chat plugin which you want to install on your website. I will take an example of [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io). You can get your code snippet from Kommunicate.

Copy the code snippet from Kommunicate Dashboard -> Settings -> Install section and paste it in just above the  tag in every page where you want the chat widget to appear.

For more details, refer:
https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/how-to-add-live-chat-plugin-to-website/

Answer (score 0):

There are many API's you could find by doing a google to do this for you.

Or you could use something like Firebase which has real time DB support that you could make a Chat with just as easily.